# condition is based on the value of the field

Tags: sql

I need to create a query in which a condition refers to a single field value.

"display 5 records whose value of the 'earnings' column does not exceed 3 times the value of the field with the smallest value" I don't know how to do it.

Comment: We need a bit more information to help you. What SQL database are you using? what tables are we working with? what have you tried etc. etc.

Comment: You will improve your chances to get a good answer by reading and following this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Literally reading your question and going step-by-step to get the answer.

There's that `emp` table that contains data about employees (`sal`, salary, included). The lowest salary is

```
SQL> select min(sal) from emp;

  MIN(SAL)
----------
       840
```

Three times lowest salary is

```
SQL> select min(sal) * 3 from emp;

MIN(SAL)*3
----------
      2520
```

Use that query as a subquery in `where` condition, as we need people whose salaries don't exceed three times lowest salary:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from emp
  3  where sal <= (select min(sal) * 3 from emp);

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17.12.80        840                    20
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20.02.81       1600        300         30
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22.02.81       1250        500         30
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28.09.81       1250       1400         30
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09.06.81       2450                    10
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08.09.81       1500          0         30
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 12.01.83       1100                    20
      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03.12.81        950                    30
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23.01.82       1300                    10

9 rows selected.
```

Finally, you said you need five rows. But, you didn't say *which* five rows. Any? That part of answer depends on database you use (you didn't specify that either) as some of them offer the `limit` clause, others don't (but have some other options available).

In Oracle, for example, *any* 5 rows would be

```
SQL> select *
  2  from emp
  3  where sal <= (select min(sal) * 3 from emp)
  4    and rownum <= 5;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17.12.80        840                    20
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20.02.81       1600        300         30
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22.02.81       1250        500         30
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28.09.81       1250       1400         30
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09.06.81       2450                    10

SQL>
```

Comment: `where sal <= (select min(sal) * 3 from emp);`
this is answer for my problem, thank you very much :)

Comment: You're welcome.